# Slow loading WPF

Tags: wpf

I've been search for a solution to a slow loading wpf form. It seems that virtualization should help me out, but I must be missing something.

I'm loading 35k orders and it takes 15 seconds to load. My guess is that virtualization isn't actually working for me.

```
<UserControl x:Class="IntTranWin.Modules.Orders.OrderSummary.OrdersSummaryView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
  <ListView BorderThickness="0" Width="Auto" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Orders.Items}" AlternationCount="2"
            IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
            VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True">
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VirtualizingStackPanel />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.View>
      <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="true" ColumnHeaderToolTip="Orders">
        <GridViewColumn Header="Number" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=OrderNumber}" Width="65" />
      </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: WPF only virtualizes the UI, so you might have to virtualize the data set also: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization

Comment: How long does it take to load the orders if you load them into a command line application (say)? Or how long does it take to display 35k pregenerated dummy orders? You need to isolate what's taking the time - is it the display or the fetching of the data from the database?

Comment: It is the UI that is the cause. When I resize the column width, the application freezes for another 15 seconds.

Comment: Tried your code with 50K records - no problem with UI freezes

Comment: 1. can you check if there's any binding error in the Immediate Window (in the Debug menu // Windows submenu) ?? Because each failed binding  raise exception. 2. try without redefining the ListView Panel, i don't know how it interfere with the VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing and VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode properties.

Comment: How are you adding your items to Orders.Items (I'm presuming its an ObservableCollection). If you are adding them after the UI has been constructed, then each time you do an add this could be causing the UI to update for each Add....thus be very slow. If you are adding a set of items to an ObservableCollection...then you need to suppress notifcations.....http://peteohanlon.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/bulk-loading-in-observablecollection/

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestions. I'm afraid the information I provided wasn't complete.

There wasn't really anything wrong with wpf I provided. The problem was in a styling of ScrollViewer for the GridView which disabled virtualization.

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
      <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <RowDefinition Height="*" />
          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DockPanel Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
          <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                        Focusable="false">
            <Border CornerRadius="4" Background="{StaticResource DefaultedBorderBrush}" Padding="4" Margin="0,4,0,4">
              <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Margin="2,0,2,0"
                                          Columns="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.Columns,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          ColumnHeaderTemplate="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplate,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          AllowsColumnReorder="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.AllowsColumnReorder,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          ColumnHeaderContextMenu="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContextMenu,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          ColumnHeaderToolTip="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderToolTip,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </Border>

          </ScrollViewer>

          <ScrollContentPresenter Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Local" />
        </DockPanel>

        <ScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1"
                   Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                   Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" />

        <ScrollBar Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                   ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}"
                   Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" />

      </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

I haven't come up with a fix. I will probably have to discard the styling and go for a different look.